# remove a row from dynamically created table using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

In my form im creating a dynamic table with the help of a template as below.

```
<table id="Newservice" style="display:none">
 <tr>
 <td><input id="type-%" style="width:100px" class="act_type" type="text" name="provider_service_dtls[#].activity_type" readonly value /></td>
<td><input id="code-%" class="act_code" style="width:150px" type="text" name="provider_service_dtls[#].activity_code"  value /></td>
<td><input id="start-%" class="datepicker" style="width:125px" type="text" name="provider_service_dtls[#].activity_start_date" value /></td>
<td><input id="clinician-%" class="clini" style="width:200px" type="text" name="provider_service_dtls[#].clinician" value /></td>
<td><input id="net-%" class="" style="width:40px" type="text" name="provider_service_dtls[#].net_amt" value /></td>
<td><input id="qty-%" class="" style="width:40px" type="text" name="provider_service_dtls[#].quantity" value />
<input type="hidden" name="provider_service_dtls.Index" value="%" />
 </td>
 <td><input id="delete" class="delete" value="X" type="button"></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
```

when clicking new button it is creating a new row to the table "Service" successfully.

Now when clicking "x" button in a row i need to delete the same.

I wrote the jquery as below

```
$('#service').on('click', buttonSelector, function () {
                $(this).closest('tr').remove();
            });
```

but it is not working..anybody done this before. Please help

Comment: `$(this).parent().parent().remove()` ?

Comment: Shouldn't `$('#service')` be `#Newservice` ? And That should work. What does `buttonSelector` consist of?

Comment: Dear Shaunak, #Newservice is the template name. while clicking new button this template is used to add a new row to the table "service"

Comment: In a link i read since it is dynamic created row the buttonselector will bind to the clicked row..is it wrong?

Comment: buttonSelector should be like this I think `:button`

Comment: Either put `'button'` there or `':button'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try update to :

```
$('#service').on('click', 'td input.delete', function () {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

Comment: Dear Jwatss, thanks its working fine..Jquery is crazy..im learning new things daily...

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help you

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".delete").bind("click", function() { 
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    });
});
```

or this

```
$(document).on('click', ".delete", function () {
 $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gayanstar/705eu5uc/)

Answer (score 1):

Try like this, you have to use event delegation since your `tr` is dynamic:

```
$(document).on('click', "input.delete", function () {
   $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are very close.

According to your code, you can simply replace your `$('#service').on()` with:

```
$('#delete').on('click', function () {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to register click event for all delete buttons but you only registered click event for `buttonSelector` which you previously selected. so you should use `'td input.delete'` selector instead of `buttonSelector`;